Declined NLN flags on old “Welcome to Italian.SE!” comments
I recently joined this site, where so far I’ve mainly been reading posts and making edits.  One thing I’ve noticed is that lots and lots of posts have the exact same comment under them:

Welcome to Italian.SE!

I can certainly see the value in commenting something like this to a new user — but personally, I’m getting a little sick of reading this under so many posts.
To be clear, I have no objection to these friendly comments being made in the first place,* but after some length of time (weeks, months, years?) surely they are just noise.  Also, I’m not talking about comments that merely start with “Welcome to Italian.SE!” but go on to say something related to the actual post — I have no problem with these.

I searched the meta for a local site policy about removing these welcome comments and found this post:  When should welcoming comments be removed?  As far as I can tell, all the voices here (and in the linked posts on the main meta site:  Should "Welcome to [site]" (and nothing else) comments be flagged? and Moderators’ behavior in small Stack Exchange communities) seem to agree that these welcome comments were fine to make, but at some point they were suitable for deletion; no one suggests that they should be kept indefinitely.
I even found this comment by one of our moderators:

For what [it] is worth I have a personal rule of thumb that I accept the flags to delete those comments only if the comments are at least 6 months old ([…] other moderators may feel differently). […]

(* Another post on our meta is critical of these comments being made; claiming that technically these comments are “against the rules”, but I think this point of view goes too far.)

So, I flagged a bunch of these comments (on posts that are several years old) as:

It's no longer needed.
This comment is outdated, conversational, or not relevant to this post.

For some reason, many of these flags have been declined (and without any indication as to why).

Why were my flags declined?

What is the value of welcome comments on posts that are several years old?

Can the site policy on welcome comments be made clearer?



I endorse DaG answer
https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1384/70
particularly when the OP adds a thankful comment. This reminds people of their first post and doesn't do any harm; to the contrary, it adds in making the site more friendly.

Once the user has been welcomed, there is not need to keep the comment, after a month the comment has been posted. That is why there is a It's no longer needed. flag reason.

@apaderno In my opinion you're wanting to make the site less friendly.

Deleting a comment that has been already read three years ago does not make the site less friendly. The comments that say Leave the tags alone! to a user but not to another user make the site less friendly.
